# Idiom(s) for: Discouraged when losing and arrogant when winning?

Tags: idiom-requests

I am looking for idiom(s) that express: Discouraged when losing and arrogant when winning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One meaning of "[**poor sport**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poor_sport)" is:

> Someone who exhibits ungracious behavior during a game, whether winning or losing.

Comment: How to use this in a sentence?

Comment: @user76911 for example, "John sure was a *poor sport*! He threw his tennis racket when he lost."